# What should our tagging protocol be for mythologies/religions?

Tags: discussion, tags

For tagging, we seem to have so far had the protocol to be that we use the region if there is one and otherwise use the name of the religion. Should that be the standard protocol that we set up for tagging? With that, so far, we've been using the demonym (i.e. Greek, Roman, Chinese) for the region but the noun (i.e. Christianity) for the religion. Should we standardize it towards one or the other or just leave that as our tagging protocol?

Comment: I had a question I tagged [tag:judeo-christian] that I retagged to [tag:christianity] when that seemed like the prevailing sentiment

Answer (score 2):

Adjectival forms are preferable, in my opinion, because there simply aren't short noun forms for things like "Greek" (we'd have to use "greek-myth", which is redundant). So we should prefer "christian" to "christianity"; "jewish" to "judaism"; and so forth.

This will be easiest to fix once we get moderators who can use moderator tools to bulk-modify tags.

Comment: Ehhh...I think newcomers (and I too) would be confused by the use of "christian" instead of "christianity". I wouldn't say that we should use only adjectives or only nouns, but whichever is clearer and/or more common. Well, I suppose using all adjectives would be okay.