# What tags should we avoid?

Tags: discussion, tags

We're already having several conversations about what our tagging protocol should be:

- [What tags should become synonyms?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-tag-synonyms-should-be-created)
- [Should we have several tags for the Maya, Inca and Aztec mythologies?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/should-we-have-separate-tags-for-the-maya-inca-and-aztec-mythologies)
- [What should our tagging protocol be for myths/religions?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-should-our-tagging-protocol-be-for-mythologies-religions)

However, in various conversations, there have been tags discussed that we don't want, that have appeared. Since we don't any moderators yet, we can't delete them easily, so we will have to do a clean-up once some are appointed. Please post below any tags, or kinds of tags, that you think should be avoided or deleted, and why.

Answer (score 8):

## Bad

- [mythical-creatures](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures) - Who is an expert on "mythical creatures" outside the context of a particular myth system? Same for [weapons](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons), [deity](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deity), [gods](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods), [magic-plant](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-plant) (!), [sea-creatures](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-creatures), [demi-gods](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demi-gods), [superhuman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superhuman)
- [meanings](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings) - What is this tag even for? I see the tag wiki, but I still don't get why we'd want this as a tag.
- [god-items](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-items) - What? What does this even mean?
- [statue](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statue) - Maybe replace with [art] or something.
- [family-tree](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family-tree) - I don't think we have any questions that require actual genealogists to chime in.

## Need clarification/etc.

- [history](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), [mythohistory](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythohistory) - These are going to need tag wikis to make clear what kinds of questions they should be used on.
- [symbolism](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) - This tag is terrible on most other fiction-based SE sites, but makes some sense here, I think. I don't know that we need to do anything with it, but it's worth keeping an eye on.

Comment: Add [tag:dieties] and [tag:god] to your list.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Both of those tags have no questions, so they'll be auto-deleted at 3:00a UTC when the deletion script runs.

Comment: For [tag:statue], maybe "representations"?

Comment: @Luna FWIW, I like [tag:art]

Comment: god-items is pretty bad. We need a tag for essentially magical items, such as Thor's hammer, Hermes' shoes or similar. Depending on whether we call them "magical", "mythical", etc., I suggest (adjective)-artifacts.

Comment: I disagree with eliminating [tag:sea-creatures] and [tag:demi-gods]. Those are a level more specific than [tag:mythical-creatures] and [tag:gods] and I think that level of specificity is sufficient.

Comment: I've recently edited [tag:history] and [tag:mythohistory] they should be in the review queue. One is for questions about factual history and the other for mythical history.

Answer (score 4):

Since the question seems to asking for tags worth avoiding in the future, as well as tags that are already problematic, I'll add a speculative answer here.

In addition to the overly vague tags senshin listed, we could potentially end up with the opposite problem of overly specific tags. SciFi.SE has had some meta discussions about "character tags" which I think apply here too. [It was summarized in this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6804) as follows:

> the consensus based on recent meta discussions is that character tags should stick around if they identify some significant subset of question that a person might be an "expert" in. In other words, it's feasible that someone could know a whole lot about Darth Vader, but not really be interested in the rest of Star Wars. OTOH, it's less likely that someone would only want to answer questions about R2-D2 -- those questions will probably be answered by people who are general Star Wars experts.

So, for example, it might be okay for us to have tags like [zeus](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeus) or [hercules](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hercules) since they have multiple stories that revolve primarily around them, and it's at least conceivable that someone would be knowledgeable about those specific stories, whereas "less popular characters" like [themis](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themis) or [charon](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charon) definitely wouldn't cut it.

Similarly, we should avoid making tags for individual books/scrolls/carvings/tablets, since [as Jeff himself said](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/410), one tag for every novel ever written would be ridiculous.

Comment: This is a really nice answer, thanks for your insight and links to SciFi SE :)

Answer (score 1):

### Bad

- [beings](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beings)
- [pantheon](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon) - I'm not even sure how this would be used.