# Should we modify our Christianity tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question [Any examples of dying and resurrecting gods that exist only in heaven, not earth?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/972/2892) got me thinking that possibly we might consider altering the "christianity" tag to something *like*:

- christian-mythology

to distinguish the way mythographers think about or treat stories in and around religious texts from the way adherents may regard them. (i.e. we're not talking about Christianity in a religious, but in a mythological, narrative and linguistic context, which may involve religion.)

Alternatively, it might be useful to have both:

- new-testament
- old-testament

---

Other relevant meta posts:

[What should our tagging protocol be for mythologies/religions?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/2892)

[What sort of separation should we have for derived religion questions?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/67/2892)

Comment: Might be mistaken, but I don't think it's technically possible to use the site's name in a tag, for obvious reasons (it's redundant). Also, "someone might be offended" is not a very good reason to do something.

Comment: I don't personally have a problem with it, nor have I seen any issues arising from the current tag but thought it was worth discussing.  I've amended the question based on your input to include alternatives that would both expand and clarify in regards to Judeo-Christian literature.

Comment: @Gibet I hear you, and if we adopt a "new-testament" tag, is that appropriate for Christian mythology which is not present in the scriptures, and how is apocrypha understood?  We do have a tag for "bible", and I could see "old-testament" and "new-testament" being useful, but clearly not a comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 5):

I'm *new* to this site, and to the whole SE network in general, so my concepts relating to tags may be slightly skewed. And in offering my 2¢ worth, I might be due some change. Still...

I do think the [christianity](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) should to be replaced or renamed, as the case may be, to [christian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian) instead, as mentioned [here](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/48/3358). Most of the other mythos-related tags have the *understood* "myth" or "mythology" in them. For example, there is [japanese](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) for Japanses mythology, [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) for Greek mythology, and [norse](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse) for Norse mythology. There are few tag for the religions themselves, such as Odinim, Dianism, or Zoroastrianism.

The [christianity](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) tag may be a rather large umbrella due to the diversity of denominations that fit under that heading. I don't know if other schools of thought, including the Greek mythologies, have such a large range or not, yet there are very few, if any, that have/had a single, undivided mythos.

I also don't think that adding [new-testament](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-testament) or [old-testament](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-testament) is necessary. No more so than the need for [poetic-edda](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetic-edda) and [prose-edda](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prose-edda), which exist. The [bible](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) tag should be good enough to cover both new- and old-testament questions, and questions of other purportedly related writings. I would even suggest that it should be used to cover the other "sacred texts" of the Christian realm, including the *Book of Mormon*, the *Pearl of Great Price*, the *Doctrine and Covenants*, and the Dead Sea Scrolls, as well as all the various "version" and "editions" of the Bible, from the Authorized King James Version, to the New World Readers Edition.

I think the "catch" here is that tags are a classification and serching *tool*, not a *solution*. The tags help to group things that are related, and filter out what is not related. If the tags are split too fine we end up with lots of tags with only a pair of questions that have no natural connection to others that are naturally related. The title of the question should be where the differentiation, if any, occurs. In the question itself is where the OP should create the filtering information that can be searched from the main site.